# Class not holding values set in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

So to simplify this, I am making a class that has a value set in the constructor as shown. When accessing this value later on it is returning an uninitialized trash value. Any ideas? I have checked the value in the constructor and it is right but as soon as it exits that scope it loses its value. It feels like a scope resolution problem but I have never experienced that in this way before.

```
class HashTable{
private:
    int tableSize;
public:
    HashTable();
    HashTable(int numBuckets);
    ~HashTable();
    int getTableSize();
}
HashTable::HashTable(int numBuckets){
    tableSize = numBuckets;
}
int HashTable::getTableSize(){
    return tableSize;
}
```

Comment: This probably doesn’t fix the problem, but you should make your constructor `explicit` and use an initialisation list.

Comment: Is this code *identical* to the one you're having trouble with? For instance, in your real code, is the constructor argument named the same as the member variable you're assigning it to?

Comment: Have you implemented the no-parameter constructor `HashTable::HashTable()` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same instance of `HashTable`?  And, are you sure you didn't accidentally make a temporary `HashTable` object?  As others have hinted at, the empty-argument constructor may paper over other errors you've made that aren't in the snippet above...

Comment: @Praetorian This part of the code is copy pasted with the hairier unrelated bits taken out. So my data member is tableSize and the constructor argument is numBuckets.

Comment: @DerFlatulator I have implemented it but left it blank as it is never called. The implementation is just HashTable::HashTable(){};

Comment: Show how you're returning the object, that code is relevant.

Comment: @JoeZ Looks like you are right. I am making another instance somewhere. I was so focused on the error being in the class I didn't think about it being outside of it. Thanks.

Comment: So are you sure you aren't calling the no parameter constructor? Because if you are you need to assign tableSize a default value

Comment: Get rid of 'HashTable();' or have a proper definition.

Comment: "I have implemented it but left it blank as it is never called." ― If it's not meant to be called, don't define it.